# Python flask ERROR You need to enable JavaScript to run this app

Tags: javascript, python, flask

[image: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.]

HTML file not working and JavaScript python flask
i have run direct html code..

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/", static_folder="/")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html") 

@app.route("/viewer/<StudyID>")
def view(StudyID):
    print ( StudyID)
    return app.send_static_file("index.html") 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8888)
```

Comment: The network request/response debugging pane doesn't have JavaScript enabled.  What's the behavior in the actual browser window?  What's the actual response from the server?  (You may need to change from "Preview" mode to something else in that debugging pane.)

Comment: The flask app is serving the static file `index.html` - what is the content of that file ?

Comment: @mfit build yarn ohif viewer